# Accessing an object within an object for jquery/underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

Can't believe this has proven so difficult.

I have the following JSON:

> {"1440071374-Bane breathing.jpg":{"filename":"1440071374-Bane
>   breathing.jpg","alt":"This is bane","primary":true,"caption":"This is
>   Banecat, the worst enemy of Batcat"}}

I've converted this into an object with the following underscore syntax:

> ```
>     _.each(results, function(r) {
>
>           var obj = JSON.parse(r.images)
> ```

Pseudo for what I want to do is as follows:

```
if primary exists and is true {

   var img = filename
```

I'd have thought it was an obvious job of just obj[0].filename but apparently not and I've been stuck on this for awhile now.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

I've come back to the problem after the weekend and I'm noticing the JSON is not being treated as an object:

```
<%
_.each(results, function(r) {

    var a = r.images;
    _.isObject(a); // strangely now resulting in false????
    _.isString(a); // true
```

When I echo the JSON onto the page using the underscore syntax `<%= r.images %>` I get the json I've pasted at the top of this question. Perhaps because the results are coming from a request it needs to be parsed first?

Comment: results is a data grid object sent as a http request. I'm using Cartalyst Data Grid.

Comment: No, like, can you post a copy of what `results` looks like so we can see if you are just accessing the data wrong? Otherwise I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: @Mathletics The output is the JSON I've posted. That line doesn't even fit into the problem I just added it for a bit of context.

Comment: That JSON doesn't have a key called `images` so either that's not an accurate representation of `results` or something else is missing here.

Comment: @Mathletics images is a field for a table of products I have. r.images is accessing this field for each product that is returned in results.

Comment: The output I've shown is the JSON contained for a single record.
Due to the data being sent as a request I'm not even sure how to show you the entire output. Part of the reason I'm finding it so hard to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is already a object (dictionary). All you need to do is iterate and validate whether `primary` is `true` and if it is, assign `filename` value to `var img`

```
var a = {"1440071374-Bane breathing.jpg":{"filename":"1440071374-Bane breathing.jpg","alt":"This is bane","primary":true,"caption":"This is Banecat, the worst enemy of Batcat"}};

for (items in a) {
  if (a[items]['primary'] == true) {
     var img = a[items]['filename'];
    alert(img);     // <-- will display 1440071374-Bane breathing.jpg in this example
 }
}
```

Same code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzLsu7yw/1). Play around with different values.

Why don't add `src` dynamically? Add the following code and it should work. Make sure that you have an `<img>` element with an unique id

`document.getElementById('imgId').src = "example.com/" + img;`

I have also edited the code in the same fiddle as above.

Comment: I've updated the question since using the addition of your code.

Comment: I'm currently getting "Cannot set property 'src' of null"

Comment: @LukeVincent Did you add `id` attribute? Its undefined if there is no elemeent for the `id` you are looking for dynamically.

Comment: Greatly appreciate your help. I've updated the question again as I find things aren't reacting the same as in jsfiddle so I wonder whether the JSON is actually being treated like an object.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it solved my problem of accessing jquery objects although I did in the end need to parse the JSON because of it coming from a request.